# Queue Length property in Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to configure Queue length for Azure Web app like we configure for Application pool in IIS server .

If so is what is the max value and does it work with Microsoft.Owin and Kestrel?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure Queue length for Azure Web app

We could [create a XDT file](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples) and apply the transforms to modify the 'Queue Length' property for application pool.

*applicationHost.xdt*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <applicationPools>
      <add name="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(queueLength)" queueLength="10">
      </add>
    </applicationPools>
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

*Result in applicationhost.config*

[image]

> what is the max value

As far as I know, the max value of the 'Queue Length' property is 65535, and the default value is 1000.

> does it work with Microsoft.Owin and Kestrel

It will be better if you could explain more about this question. Or you could modify the 'Queue Length' property for your application pool via XDT file, if it causes Microsoft.Owin and Kestrel not working fine, you could post detailed error.

Comment: My understanding of queue is it will hold the requests when the application cant handle the speed and pushes to application when it has capacity to process them which is different from a message queues  where application has to pull the requests from the queue,

Comment: If my above understanding is correct there must be an understanding or protocol kind of thing for communication to happen between application pool and web application to check for the availability, Unlike ASP.net where both the components are in sync and understand each other OWIN components which developed based on commo spec which are supposed to work with any server will the queue concept of application pool work or simply will the communication happen ?

Comment: [This blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/brenle/2015/03/06/modifying-the-queue-length-for-exchange-app-pools-in-iis/) explained what is the queue length setting in IIS and how does it work, please read it.